# How exactly does Tor prevent ISPs from viewing internet activity?

Tags: help

From what I understand, I am connected to the internet via my ISP. Therefore, all my internet requests are going from my computer through my ISP to wherever. So, my question is, how does Tor prevent my ISP from seeing these requests? Does the Tor browser encrypt the requests that are sent from my computer before they reach my ISP?

Comment: Yes. https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en#thesolution

Comment: Really wish this had a simple direct answer (disclaimer: I am just as clueless as OP), Simply put, If I am to call my ISP, what URL would they see that I am browsing when I am using tor browser. @cacahuatl 's comment describes how the data is processed after reaching ISP not what ISP is actually looking at